A simple authentication mechanism drogon
The encryption is temporary.
I have a quite unreadable error with all the instances execSqlAsync function.
The error is:
In template: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::stringstream' (aka 'basic_stringstream<char>') and 'std::exception') error occurred here in instantiation of function template specialization 'drogon::orm::Field::as<std::exception>' requested here in instantiation of function template specialization 'drogon::orm::internal::CallbackHolder<(lambda at /Users/<br>
41:13)>::makeValue<std::exception>' requested here in instantiation of function template specialization 'drogon::orm::internal::CallbackHolder<(lambda at /Users/
<br>
41:13)>::run<1UL>' requested here in instantiation of function template specialization 'drogon::orm::internal::CallbackHolder<(lambda at <br>
41:13)>::run<true>' requested here in instantiation of member function 'drogon::orm::internal::CallbackHolder<(lambda at /Users/<br>
41:13)>::execCallback' requested here in instantiation of function template specialization 'drogon::orm::internal::CallbackHolder<(lambda at /Users/<br>
41:13)>::CallbackHolder<(lambda at patr... in instantiation of function template specialization 'drogon::orm::internal::SqlBinder::operator>><(lambda at 
<br>
 server/AuthController.cpp:41:13), drogon::orm::internal::FunctionTraits<(lambda at /U... in instantiation of function template specialization 'drogon::orm::DbClient::execSqlAsync<(lambda at <br> server/AuthController.cpp:35:13), (lambda at /<br> server/A... candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter '_CharT' ('char' vs. 'std::exception') candidate template ignored: could not match 'uniform_int_distribution<_IT>' against 'std::exception' candidate template ignored: could not match '_CharT[_Np]' against 'std::exception' candidate template ignored: could not match 'unsigned char[_Np]' against 'std::exception' candidate template ignored: could not match 'signed char[_Np]' against 'std::exception' candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>' against 'std::exception' candidate template ignored: could not match 'bitset<_Size>' against 'std::exception' candidate template ignored: requirement 'integral_constant<bool, false>::value' was not satisfied [with _Stream = std::stringstream &, _Tp = std::exception &] candidate template ignored: could not match '__iom_t7<_MoneyT>' against 'std::exception' candidate template ignored: could not match '__iom_t9<_CharT>' against 'std::exception'

And here is the code:
#include "AuthController.h"
#include <drogon/drogon.h>
#include <drogon/orm/DbClient.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace drogon;
using namespace drogon::orm;

// Simple Caesar Cipher function
std::string caesarCipher(const std::string& text, int shift) {
    std::string result = text;
    std::transform(result.begin(), result.end(), result.begin(),
                   [shift](char c) -> char {
                       if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
                           return 'a' + (c - 'a' + shift) % 26;
                       else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
                           return 'A' + (c - 'A' + shift) % 26;
                       else
                           return c;
                   });
    return result;
}

void AuthController::signup(const HttpRequestPtr &req, std::function<void(const HttpResponsePtr &)> &&callback) {
    auto json = req->getJsonObject();
    std::string username = json->get("username", "").asString();
    std::string password = json->get("password", "").asString();

    // Encrypt the password using Caesar cipher
    std::string encryptedPassword = caesarCipher(password, 3);

    auto client = drogon::app().getDbClient().get();
    client->execSqlAsync(
            "INSERT INTO users (username, password_hash) VALUES ($1, $2)",
            [callback](const Result &result) {
                auto response = HttpResponse::newHttpResponse();
                response->setStatusCode(HttpStatusCode::k200OK);
                response->setBody("Signup successful");
                callback(response);
            },
            [callback](const std::exception &e) {  // Correct exception handling
                auto response = HttpResponse::newHttpResponse();
                response->setStatusCode(HttpStatusCode::k500InternalServerError);
                response->setBody(e.what());
                callback(response);
            },
            username, encryptedPassword);
}

void AuthController::login(const HttpRequestPtr &req, std::function<void(const HttpResponsePtr &)> &&callback) {
    auto json = req->getJsonObject();
    std::string username = json->get("username", "").asString();
    std::string password = json->get("password", "").asString();

    auto client = drogon::app().getDbClient();
    client.get()->execSqlAsync(
            "SELECT password_hash FROM users WHERE username = $1",
            [password, callback](const Result &result) {
                std::shared_ptr<HttpResponse> response;
                if (!result.empty()) {
                    std::string storedHash = result[0]["password_hash"].as<std::string>();
                    std::string decryptedPassword = caesarCipher(storedHash, -3);
                    if (decryptedPassword == password) {
                        response = HttpResponse::newHttpResponse();
                        response->setStatusCode(k200OK);
                        response->setBody("Login successful");
                    } else {
                        response = HttpResponse::newHttpResponse();
                        response->setStatusCode(k401Unauthorized);
                        response->setBody("Login failed");
                    }
                } else {
                    response = HttpResponse::newHttpResponse();
                    response->setStatusCode(k401Unauthorized);
                    response->setBody("User not found");
                }
                callback(response);
            },
            [callback](const std::exception &e) {
                auto resp = HttpResponse::newHttpResponse();
                resp->setStatusCode(k500InternalServerError);
                resp->setBody(e.what());
                callback(resp);
            },
            username);
}


what is your question? In which line is the error?

at client->execSqlAsync at the signup

but it is the same at the login

do you know a way to make it more readable?

copy it in a way the keeps the formatting then select it all and press the {} button, alternatively embedd it in three backticks as it is now

Problem is wrong argument of lambda. From what I was able to find it should be: [callback](const drogon::orm::DrogonDbException& e) https://github.com/drogonframework/drogon/wiki/ENG-08-1-Database-DbClient#execsqlasync please learn how to read documentation of library you are using.

Can you write it as a solution so I will upvote you?

Remember to post link to library you are using.
After I was able to google this library and inspecting documentation solution is clear:
ENG 08 1 Database DbClient · drogonframework/drogon Wiki · GitHub

After the execution of sql is successful, the execution result is wrapped by the Result class and passed to the user through the result callback function; if there is any exception in the sql execution, the exception callback function is executed, and the user can obtain the exception information from the DrogonDbException object.
Let us give an example:
clientPtr->execSqlAsync("select * from users where org_name=$1",
                            [](const drogon::orm::Result &result) {
                                std::cout << result.size() << " rows selected!" << std::endl;
                                int i = 0;
                                for (auto row : result)
                                {
                                    std::cout << i++ << ": user name is " << row["user_name"].as<std::string>() << std::endl;
                                }
                            },
                            [](const DrogonDbException &e) {
                                std::cerr << "error:" << e.base().what() << std::endl;
                            },
                            "default");


so you should your code this way:
            [callback](const DrogonDbException &e) {  // Correct exception handling
                auto response = HttpResponse::newHttpResponse();
                response->setStatusCode(HttpStatusCode::k500InternalServerError);
                response->setBody(e.base().what());
                callback(response);
            },

Offtopic:
This part of code:
response->setBody(e.base().what());

May look handy at first glance, but can be also security threat, since it can leak confidential information about structure of you database. This way it could be easier for attacker to discover weaknesses in your software (like SQL injection).
